# Invalid entitlements only when profiling, archiving and building works fine

Tags: ios, xcode, profiling

I'm having trouble profiling my app while connected to a device and get the dreaded "Invalid Entitlements" error. Building and archiving work fine with the current provisioning profiles. Any idea?

Comment: This question is short on info...I expect better from someone with this kind of rep.  Are you using an entitlements plist?  What does it look like?  Are you using a developer or distribution profile?  -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid entitlements basically means that the entitlements specified in your provisioning profile are not equivalent to the ones specified in your applications entitlements.plist.

A couple of options:

-Open up both your plist and provisioning profile as a textfile and compare the entitlements sections to see that they match and change your plist to match your profile or...

-Use Xcode 4.2 where you don't need an entitlements.plist file and just delete it. I think this may have started with Xcode 4.